# Reload page after Changing URL

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, url, firefox

I want to add a text in the URL after # and then reload the page.

I have done:

```
<a href="current_url+'#'+sample" onclick="location.reload();">Click Here</a>
```

and it is working fine in Google Chrome, but in firefox it reloads the page but the url fragment '#sample' is not there. That means it gets me back on the same page without the # string. But I need it for sure.

I have also tried:

```
$('a').click(function(){
          location.reload(true);       //even window.location.reload(true);
});
```

But got no positive result.

What should I do?

Comment: and why do you need to reload the page after adding a hash tag to it?

Comment: Using the hash to reload the page sounds kinda weird, since the hashpart is used to do exactly the opposite, prevent a reload, but still change the url. What are you trying to do?

Comment: On page load I detect the text after hash and send it to a controller with ajax and change the content on the page accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps you can do just that, update the page with a callback of `data` from your ajax call...without needing to reload the page?

Comment: I agree with @camelCase on this one

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by adding the link in the onclick (with window.location) of the anchor tag.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.location='current_url+'#'+sample'; location.reload();">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you take the current url i.e. `document.location.href` and add it the text you want:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeUrl(sample);">Click Here</a>

function changeUrl(text) {
    document.location.href = document.location.href + "#" + text;
}
```

Note that this solution doesn't require jQuery.

Comment: I have also tried it.. but it does not help.. also i can't add javascript:void in href... i want a url only

Comment: Then, using jQuery `$('a').attr('href', $('a').attr('href') + "#" + sample);` ?